# Recursive function and memorization to find minimum operations to transform n to 1

Tags: python, python-2.x, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm a new, self-taught programmer working on the Google FooBar challenge.  I've submitted my answer (code at bottom) and it was accepted, but I'd like suggestions on how to improve my solution.

**Challenge**: return minimum number of operations to transform a positive integer to 1. Valid operations are: n+1, n-1, or n/2.

**My solution**
I started with a recursive function, but ran into a runtime error with very large numbers.  I added memorization using a global variable to store values that had already been computed, but this seems inelegant.  (I think it's discouraged to use global variables?)

Suggestions on how I might improve the below solution?

```
paths = {1:0, 2:1}

def shortest_path(num):
    if num in paths:
        return paths[num]

    if num % 2 == 0:
        paths[num] = 1 + shortest_path(num / 2)
    else:
        paths[num] = min(2 + shortest_path((num+1)/2), 
                         2 + shortest_path((num-1)/2))
    return paths[num]

def answer(n):
    num = int(n)
    return shortest_path(num)
```

Test cases:

```
n = 15 --> 5
n = 293523 --> 25
n = 191948125412890124637565839228475657483920292872746575849397998765432345689031919481254128901246375658392284756574839202928727465758493979987654323456890319194812541289012463756583922847565748392029287274657584939799876543234568903 --> 1029
```

- The input number can be up to 309 digits long hence the final test case

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401447/python-recursive-function-error-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded). If you issue is with larger numbers and you are getting a `maximum recursion depth exceeded` error then the post might help you.

Comment: thanks!  I actually don't have a problem with recursion - sorry if that was confusing in my post.  The code I posted works even with very large numbers.  I was just wondering if there's a more elegant way to write it instead of using the global variable paths.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you could remove the global variable by moving the memoization to a decorator and adding a base case scenario to the function.

```
from functools import wraps

def memoize(func):
    cache = {}

    @wraps(func)
    def inner(*args):
        if args not in cache:
            cache[args] = func(*args)
        return cache[args]

    return inner


@memoize
def shortest_path(num):
    if num <= 2:
        return num - 1

    if num % 2 == 0:
        return 1 + shortest_path(num/2)

    else:
        return min(2 + shortest_path((num + 1)/2), 
                   2 + shortest_path((num - 1)/2))
```

To address the recursion depth error, you could either change [`sys.setrecursionlimit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit), or you could rewrite your initial solution to use `paths` as an argument to avoid the global variable.

```
def shortest_path(num, paths=None):
    paths = paths or {1: 0, 2: 1}

    if num in paths:
        return paths[num]

    if num % 2 == 0:
        paths[num] = 1 + shortest_path(num/2, paths)
    else:
        paths[num] = min(2 + shortest_path((num+1)/2, paths), 
                         2 + shortest_path((num-1)/2, paths))

    return paths[num]
```

Or, as suggested in the other answer, test the number modulo 4 to figure out which path to take and avoid recursion all together.

```
def shortest_path(n):
    count = 0

    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            count += 1
            n = n / 2
        elif n % 4 == 1 or n == 3:
            count += 2
            n = (n - 1) / 2
        elif n % 4 == 3:
            count += 2
            n = (n + 1) / 2

    return count
```

Comment: Better yet: `from functools import lru_cache` (3.2+). However, if I remember correctly, foobar uses Python 2.7, so it's only useful for the general case.

Comment: @Mego Yep, I only have Python 2.7 on the machine I was working on, so I couldn't test/post that solution.

Comment: @JaredGoguen Yup it's only 2.7.  I tried your solution with a test case (I've edited my original post to include the test case+answer) and am getting a recursion depth error.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

The problems you've encountered usually signal that the approach is not the best.

Consider the very first step in your algorithm: you are definite that if the number is even, the best action is \$n\rightarrow \frac{n}{2}\$ (*why?*).

Try to apply the same logic one step further. Let \$n\$ be odd. Either \$\frac{n+1}{2}\$ or \$\frac{n-1}{2}\$ is also odd (*why?*). The best action is to pick that which is even (*why?*).

As soon as you prove all the *why* statements, a straight-forward non-recursive algorithm is easy to obtain.